# How to redirect to home page before initate the dom and datas?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have 3 pages, the 2nd page supplying the data to 3rd page. it works fine. the issue is when the 3rd page refreshed by user, I would like to navigate home page. since there is no data available for 3rd page.

I try like this:

```
constructor(private store: StorageService, 
      private sharedData: SharedDatasService, 
      private location:Location,
      private route:Router) {

      console.log('this.sharedData.validationDatas', this.sharedData.validationDatas );

      if(Object.keys(this.sharedData.validationDatas).length === 0 ) { //there is not data.. go to home.
          this.route.navigate(['']);
          return;
      }

    }
```

But still I am getting the error from `DOM` compile. and my page not redirecting to home page at all...

how to handle this?

error i am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'book.label.title.packageSizes' of undefined
```

Comment: from which component are you getting this error?
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'book.label.title.packageSizes'`

Comment: from same page only

Comment: Simply I ask, without read the `DOM` and just entering to page, by condition I would like to redirect

Comment: Is this.sharedData.validationDatas an array?

Comment: No, that's an Object, I declared like : `validationDatas:any = {};`

Comment: what does console log returns for `this.sharedData.validationDatas` , if return `undefined` you should just change your `if` condition to `if(this.sharedData.validationDatas)`

Comment: consoles like `this.sharedData.validationDatas {}`

Comment: @3gwebtrain glad that it helped

Comment: It would be great if you could rename the title to make more meaningful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Route Guards to achieve this.

In your **route config**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'secondPage', component: SecondPage},
  {
    path: 'thridpage',
    component: ThridPage,
    canActivate: [DataCheckRouteGuard],
  }
];
```

**DataCheckRouteGuard**

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { sharedData} from './SharedDatasService';

@Injectable()
export class DataCheckRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private sharedData: SharedDatasService) {}

  canActivate() {
  if(this.sharedData.validationDatas!==undefined) 
   {
     return true;
   } else 
   {
   // No data so navigate to second page
    this.router.navigate(['/secondPage'] 

    return false
   }
  }
}
```

[Usage of  routes](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/route_guards.html)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my HTML label by condition, it works fine now.

here is the update:

it was :

```
{{getLabel('book.label.title.packageSizes')}}
```

it is now :

```
{{getLabel('book?.label.title.packageSizes')}}
```